# Difference between elem and elem[0] in angularJS custom directives?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, element

```
angular.module('todomvc')
.directive('todoFocus', function ($timeout) {
    'use strict';

    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.todoFocus, function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    elem[0].focus();
                }, 0, false);
        });
    };
});
```

I was analyzing a custom directive of a JS sample code (angularJS) lately and I came across this line which frustrated me.

```
elem[0].focus();
```

When I tried to change elem[0].focus(); to elem.focus(); The whole directive just doesn't work. But in my previous attempt to create a custom directive that include elem.bind('keydown', someFunction(){}); elem alone without the [0] worked fine.

So my question is: What's the difference between elem and elem[0] in creating these custom directives?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `console.log(elem)` inside the `return` function. Seems it is an array of few elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per angularJs [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), it returns jQuery object. If you are annoyed with `elem[0].focus()`  you can use `$(elem).focus()`

Answer (score 0):

Basically these are obvious differences;

1. elem is the jQlite instance in angular
2. elem[0] is the native javascript object and there is no jQlite
   instance so you can't use any jquery DOM method but only native
   methods in javascript.